# How to make LALR(1) parser directly?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I studied LR(1) parsers and then LALR(1) and noticed that if we want to construct LALR(1) parsers, we should FIRST construct the LR(1) parser and then, by combining some states with the same core, we can go ahead for LALR(1) parser. (For complex grammars, it's not easy to construct LR parsers)

Now a question comes to mind: can we make LALR(1) parser DIRECTLY? Without using (Or maybe constructing) LR(1) parser? If Yes, How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. It's quite easy to search for the algorithm. It's described in every decent book about parsing.  In any case the general idea is that you build the set of states for SLR and then augment the states with some information about the following characters using a propagation trick. LALR(1) parsers always have the same states as SLR.

Comment: @Bakuriu I studied Aho's book second edition, In the LALR(1) section, It has just pointed to algorithm you mean (construction from SLR(1)). Instead he gave an example of constructing LALR(1) by using LR(1) states. (p268)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PARSING TECHNIQUES A Practical Guide by Dick Grune and Ceriel J.H. Jacobs is worth getting. The Lemon Parser generator (http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) has readable code too.